# How to fix AngularJS with RequireJS racing issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am using requirejs with angularjs and I am getting some sort of racing issue where the page will load great about 9/10 times, but will throw an undefined object the other time. Here is the offending code.

```
define("app", ["angular", "angular-resource", "angular-route", "components/app/app-ctrl"], function (angular) {  
    var app = angular.module("app", [
        "ngResource", 
        "ngRoute", 
        "app.myApp2",
        "app.myApp3"
    ]).config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            controller: "appCtrl2", 
            templateUrl: "/app/partials/first.html"
        }).when("/dashboard", {
            controller: "appCtrl3", 
            templateUrl: "/app/partials/second.html"
        }).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);

    angular.element().ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
    });

    return app;
});
```

Now I know that if I take the myApp2, myApp3 modules out of the loading area of app than the error goes away. However if I leave it in there, the error occurs on the angular.boostrap code. I think this could be fixed if I can move the loading of myApp2, myApp3 components down to be after the bootstrap. Along with the config. Is this possible? Keep in mind I still need to return app so other requirejs modules can use it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding a require statement around the bootstrap which requires all components that need to be loaded prior to the inital bootstrap. In case this helps anyone when using RequireJS with Angular.

```
define("app", ["angular", "require", "angular-resource", "angular-route", "components/app/app-ctrl"], function (angular, require) {  
    var app = angular.module("app", [
        "ngResource", 
        "ngRoute", 
        "app.myApp2",
        "app.myApp3"
    ]).config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/", {
            controller: "appCtrl2", 
            templateUrl: "/app/partials/first.html"
        }).when("/dashboard", {
            controller: "appCtrl3", 
            templateUrl: "/app/partials/second.html"
        }).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }]);

    angular.element().ready(function() {
        require(["myApp2", "myApp3"], function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
        });
    });

    return app;
});
```